# Create a dictionary by keys and values

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary dico which contains elements like this:

```
<key>           <values>
comb_element     pageId1, pageId2, .. pageIdn
```

comb_element are elements of list of tuple comb :

I try with this code to create dico, but I didn't get the correct format of dico

```
comb=list(set(product(data['OsId'], data['BrowserId'])))
dico={}
dico[tuple(comb)] = list(data['PageId'])
```

Here what contains comb :

```
[(12, 16),
 (33, 11),
 (99, 11),
 (11, 14),
 (33, 14),
 (32, 12),
 (99, 14),
 (11, 11),
 (11, 17),
 (32, 15),
 (99, 17),
 (33, 17),
 (11, 99),
 (33, 99),
 (99, 99),
 (12, 12),
 (12, 15),
 (32, 11),
 (11, 16),
 (33, 16),
 (32, 14),
 (99, 16),
 (32, 17),
 (32, 99),
 (12, 11),
 (12, 14),
 (12, 17),
 (12, 99),
 (11, 12),
 (99, 15),
 (33, 12),
 (99, 12),
 (11, 15),
 (32, 16),
 (33, 15)]
```

Here the dataframe data: in case of (12, 16) as key I would like to attribute the lis of page : 1005581 and  1016529.

```
Cluster PageId     OsId BrowserId   
0         1005581   11  16  
0         1016529   11  16  
0         1016529   11  17  
0         1016529   12  14  
0         1016529   12  16
```

So for example,
any idea to fix it? thanks

Comment: Can you please print `tuple(comb)`, or just `comb`, to give more information to help answer your question?

Comment: @constantstranger just edit to respond to your question, thanks

Comment: OK, thanks. It looks like `comb` is a `list` of `tuples`, and I assume that each such `tuple`, for example, (12, 16), is a `comb_element`. Just to take an example, what is the `list` of page ids that you want to be the value for `comb_element` (12, 16)? What about for `comb_element` (33, 11)? It may also be helpful to see what is in `data['PageId']`.

Comment: @constantstranger I just edit my post; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code below might do what you want.

Assuming you have the dataframe in list-of-dicts format, you can just build up the entries in the dictionary `dico` by appending the 'PageId' value to a `list` with the (OsId, BrowserId) `tuple` as its key.

This way you don't need to bother with using `product()` to get all possible combinations of (OsId, BrowserId), some of which may have no matching PageIds.

```
        df_as_list_of_dicts = [
            {'Cluster' : 0, 'PageId' : 1005581, 'OsId' : 11, 'BrowserId' : 16},
            {'Cluster' : 0, 'PageId' : 1016529, 'OsId' : 11, 'BrowserId' : 16},
            {'Cluster' : 0, 'PageId' : 1016529, 'OsId' : 11, 'BrowserId' : 17},
            {'Cluster' : 0, 'PageId' : 1016529, 'OsId' : 12, 'BrowserId' : 14},
            {'Cluster' : 0, 'PageId' : 1016529, 'OsId' : 12, 'BrowserId' : 16},
        ]
        dico = {}
        for row in df_as_list_of_dicts:
            tup = (row['OsId'], row['BrowserId'])
            if tup not in dico:
                dico[tup] = []
            dico[tup].append(row['PageId'])
        [print(f"{key} : {value}") for key, value in dico.items()]
```

Sample output:

```
(11, 16) : [1005581, 1016529]
(11, 17) : [1016529]
(12, 14) : [1016529]
(12, 16) : [1016529]
```